# How pino is faster than other library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, pino

Pino is fastest json logger in the town but how it achieves better performance than others like winston, bunyan, morgan? As per https://www.nearform.com/blog/pino-the-fastest-node-js-logger-for-production/

1. Optimized JS code, e.g. for serialisation and string operations
2. Pino streams logs in line-delimited JSON format to any given output stream (default: standard output stream)

can someone elaborate point 1 and 2 with example?